# How to delete a character in password masking c++

Tags: c++

I'm currently making a login form for my project, but I can't move on on this one. I want my program to delete a character(in password) when I'm pressing the backspace button, but the program is not reading it.

Here's my code

```
string username, password, power;
char ast=' ';
int aste = 0, accessLevel;
ofstream addAcc;
addAcc.open("Accounts.txt");
cout<<"Username: ";cin.ignore();getline(cin, username);
cout<<"Password:  ";
do
{
    ast = getch();

    if (ast == 13 || ast == ' ' )
    {
        break;
    }
    if(ast==8 || password!="")
    {
        cout<<"\b \b";
        password.erase(password.size()-1);
    }
    cout<<"*";
    password+=ast;
    aste ++;
}while(ast!=13 || ast!=' ');
do
{
    cout<<"Enter Access Level(0-1):  ";cin>>accessLevel;
    switch(accessLevel)
    {
        case 0:
            {
                power = "Cashier";
                break;
            }
        case 1:
            {
                power = "Manager";
                break;
            }
        default: 
            cout<<"Invalid access level."<<endl;
    }
}while(accessLevel>1||accessLevel<0);
```

Thank you for those who will help.

Comment: DAT INDENT STYLE. Apart from that, why the hassle with backspace? Any sane modern console shall support proper behavior with backspace at least. In addition, magic numbers are horrible.

Comment: Try using KEY_BACKSPACE instead of 8.  ncurses may be returning a different code.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm kinda new in this programming language. But i have researched a bit about ncurses. I would just like to clarify if I have to download the library or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some platforms `getch()` will return the DEL character (ascii 127) when you hit BACKSPACE. So change your line

```
if(ast==8 || password!="")
```

to

```
if((ast==8 || ast==127) && !password.empty())
```

You probably don't want to erase a character everytime that `password` is not an empty string either, so I removed `|| password!=""` from the condition too. Instead you want to erase one character *only* if the password is not empty. So you need an `&&` instead of an `||`.

Also note, that you're adding the character returned by `getch()` unconditionally. So if the user enters BACKSPACE, you erase the last character, but append BACKSPACE to the password. So you should only append the character returned by `getch()` if it was not a BACKSPACE (or DEL).

Thus your code might look like this:

```
if((ast==8 || ast==127) && !password.empty())
{
    cout<<"\b \b";
    password.erase(password.size()-1);
    aste--;
}
else
{
    password+=ast;
    cout<<"*";
    aste++;
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle the user pressing backspace at the beginning of the string very well, does it?

Answer (score 0):

do
        {
            c = _getch();

```
        if (c == 13 || c == ' ') // checking ascii key 13 pressed or no
        {
            break;
        }
        if (c == 8 || c == 127)
        {
            if (Password.size() != 0){
                cout << "\b \b";
                Password.erase(Password.size() - 1);
                StarNum--;
            }

        }
        else {
            Password += c;
            cout << "*";
            StarNum++;
        }
    } while (c != 13 || c != ' ');
```

Comment: You also should explain why it is a working piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
#include <conio.h>
```

and

```
ch = _getch();
```

instead ch = getch();

and also change the condition like this

```
if(ch == 8)
{
    password.erase(password.size()-1);
    aste--;
}else
{
    password +=ch;
    aste++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for answering. I did what you said, but still didn't fix the problem.  I have done this in c# and is working properly, but when I tried to translate the code in c++, only the backspace button is not working.

Comment: It's working correctly for me! what problem you're getting? do you get any error or run time error?